# ASP.NET MVC: Create Crawlable link tags from rendered pager

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, seo

I would like to take links that I am using from within an ASP.NET MVC application and create `<link>` tags using the Previous and Next page URLs from a rendered pager that's using the **PagedListPager** helper.  Originally I had planned on using JavaScript and jQuery to get the URLs of these links after the page was rendered.  However, after doing some research, this method will not allow these `<link>` tags to be **crawlable**.

So now I'm wondering if there is a clever client-side/Javascript approach of grabbing these URLs and making these `<link>` tags crawlable.

PagedListPager Code:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Catalogs, page => Url.Action("Books", new {BookName = Model.Book.DisplayAs, bookId = Model.BookId, page}), new PagedListRenderOptions { FunctionToTransformEachPageLink = (liTag, aTag) => { aTag.Attributes.Remove("rel"); liTag.InnerHtml = aTag.ToString(); return liTag; }})
```

The code above will render the pager just fine.  Now I want to know if there is a way to use **Javascript** & **jQuery** such as below to make the link crawlable:

```
 if ($('.PagedList-skipToPrevious')[0]){
        $('.PagedList-skipToPrevious').children('a').removeAttr('rel');
        var prev_link = $('.PagedList-skipToPrevious').children('a').attr('href');

        var prev = document.createElement('link');
        prev.rel = 'prev';
        prev.href = prev_link;
        document.head.appendChild(prev);

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered providing a "view all" page and setting the paged versions as `noindex`?

https://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-and-seo-best-practices-common-issues/

Comment: Here is a link to what I'm trying to accomplish using `rel` tags of `prev` and `next` dynamically: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en